# Using XPath Predicate to select value based on qualifers inside loop

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, biztalk

I have the following XSL to select a value from the C50602 element, based on the value in the NAD01 elment and the C50601 element using Xpath predicates. There is a looping functoid on the NADLoop1.

```
<CustomerReference>
    <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='EFACT_D96A_ORDERS']/*[local-name()='NADLoop1'][NAD01 = 'SN']/*[local-name()='RFFLoop2']/*[local-name()='RFF_2']/*[local-name()='C506_2'][C50601 = 'IT']/*[local-name()='C50602']"></xsl:value-of>
</CustomerReference>
```

The code is inline XSLT inside a scripting functoid. However, when I execute it, I do not get a value in my CustomerReference element, though I get no errors.

The ingoing RFFLoop2 element is as follow:

```
<ns0:RFFLoop2>
      <ns0:RFF_2>
        <ns0:C506_2>
          <C50601>IT</C50601>
          <C50602>1135</C50602>
        </ns0:C506_2>
      </ns0:RFF_2>
    </ns0:RFFLoop2>
```

I've used the xPath documentation from here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

What is wrong with my current predicates? I expect the value '1135' to be mapped to my CustomerReference element.

Comment: Can you show more of your XML please? Your XPath is looking for elements such as `EFACT_D96A_ORDERS` and `NAD01` which are not shown in your sample. Thanks!

Comment: Also, `NAD01` and `C50601` name tests ask for elements in the empty namespace URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried.

```
//*[local-name()='RFFLoop2']/*[local-name()='RFF_2']/*[local-name()='C506_2'][C50601 = 'IT']/*[local-name()='C50602']
```

in freeformatter.com, your xpath is working fine.

[image]

try to change `[NAD01 = 'SN']` to `[*[local-name()='NAD01'] = 'SN']`

Comment: Thanks, I discovered that the problem lay elsewhere in the map. There was another functoid which changed the value to NULL after my code inserted the value. I will mark this as answered.